# Replacre UNICODE characters in UTF-8 string

Tags: c#, encoding

I am having problem with UTF-8 string that contains UNICODE replacements instead of actual characters. The string comes from 3rd party app and looks like this:

```
"Jedin%C3%A1%20spr%C3%A1vn%C3%A1%20volba;"
```

I need it to look like this:

```
"Jediná správná volba"
```

Is there a way to replace UNICODE with actual characters from UTF-8? I already tried to use `System.Encoding` class but it did not work for me.

Comment: `Uri.UnescapeDataString(string)`? [Example](https://rextester.com/CKNZG81184)

Comment: Thats definitely it ... Thanks!